# Cannot load assembly (hr = 0x80131018)

Tags: .net, assemblies, autocad

I have a user with issues loading a .Net assembly into AutoCAD. I get the following error:

> Cannot load assembly. Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly (hr = 0x80131018)

They are using an anit virus package called Endpoint Security and when this is turned off, the load works.

I am not a .Net expert and was hoping there might be a friendlier solution than me suggesting the user put their anti virus package in the trash!? But I've no idea where to start, any help would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resource dll with Native Code whyle expected .NET resource dll. When I slip right one - everything become ok.

Answer (score -1):

System.BadImageFormatException can happen if you are mismatching x86 / AnyCpu. Try to compile your assembly in **x86** mode explictly and see what happens.

Comment: I thought it was that at 1st, because my application has a version compiled for both x86 and x64. But that would produce a different error code it seems, (hr = 0x8007000b). Furthermore, I forced it to load the correct dll for the CPU and I got the same error. It's something else and like I said, everything works when anti virus is switched off. I just don't know why and having the user switching off anti virus forever is not an option.