# Could not load file or assembly (custom dll) - works for console but fails for web project (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a ASP.NET MVC 5 web app that utilizes SignalR for the communication stack abstraction.

Everything works fine until I add a custom DLL that implements a real-time message bus. Part of the message bus process requires xml files (properly copied to bin deploy folder).

When trying to run the Web project (locally using IISExpress) I am getting a "Could not load file or assembly 'MSG_BUS.DLL' or one of its dependencies" ... **everything works fine when running from a console project** which makes me think its on the ASP.NET MVC part

Any idea how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue? I suspect it has something to do with the XML files - but have no clue how to resolve it

**UPDATE**
I should have mentioned the native part of my dependant DLL, this helped me move forward: [Native Assembly Binding fails for ASP.NET solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869621/native-assembly-binding-fails-for-asp-net-solution)

Comment: That duplicate answer doesn't answer why I have no dependency issues when running in a console project - can you help me with that part?

Comment: Maybe you can try the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get more detailed info on exactly what is failing. It could possibly be that your MSG_BUS.dll has an additional dependency that is missing. You might also find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/1373170

Comment: Do you have same target architecture?

Comment: yes - same architecture, nothing in binding errors. It works in a console app which is part of the same solution

Comment: this turned out to be my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869621/native-assembly-binding-fails-for-asp-net-solution I should have mentioned the native DLL part of my problem